# Are there limitations with non-zero boundary conditions using ode45 on linearized systems in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

First of all, I know the simple answer is yes. I have a few functions and a script that I am calling to try to solve a mechanical model with. I have a function of constants:

```
   function [m1, m2, m3, M, alpha, R, g, l, kys, I3, k1, k2, c1, c2, kr] = variable_constants2()
m1=2500;
m2=1500;
m3=8000;
M=m1+m2+m3;
alpha=pi/8;
R=10;
g=-9.81;
l=2*R*sin(alpha)/alpha;
kys=(1/(72*alpha))*(18*alpha^2+9*alpha*sin(2*alpha)...
    -32*sin(alpha)^2);
I3=m3*kys;
k1=1e4;
k2=1e4;
c1=1e4;
c2=1e4;  
kr=1e4;
end
```

I have a function which defines my mass matrix of the system (yes I know that many variables are unused, I am just leaving them there for now):

```
function M = mass(q)
    [m1, m2, m3, M, alpha, R, g, l, kys, I3, k1, k2, c1, c2 kr] = variable_constants2();
    M = zeros(6,6);
    M(1,1)=1;
    M(2,2)=-(2*m3+m1);
    M(2,6)=-(2*m3*l*sin(q(5)));
    M(3,3)=1;
    M(4,4)=-m2;
    M(5,5)=1;
    M(6,6)=-(2*I3-2*m3*l);
end
```

I have a function that sets up the state-space model in the form of q_dot  = M^-1*q. where q is the matrix of state variables of the system:

```
function dYdt = f(t,q,P)
    [m1, m2, m3, M, alpha, R, g, l, kys, I3, k1, k2, c1, c2 kr] = variable_constants2();
    q_matrix=[q(2)
        k1*q(1)+k2*(q(3)-q(1))+m1*g+2*m3*g+q(2)*(c1+c2)+q(6)^2*cos(q(5))
        q(4)
        k2*(q(3)-q(1))+m2*g+q(4)*(c1+c2)
        q(6)
        2*m3*l*q(6)*q(2)*cos(q(5)) + 2*kr*q(5) + 2*m3*l*(g*sin(q(5)) ...
            +q(2)*sin(q(5))*q(6))];
    M = mass2(q);
    dYdt = M\q_matrix;
end
```

And finally, there is a script that I am trying to run which calculates the solution to this differential equation set:

```
[m1, m2, m3, M, alpha, R, g, l, kys, I3, k1, k2, c1, c2, kr] = variable_constants2();
tspan = linspace(0,50,100);
Y0=[-0.564513980920171,-8.788646829574525,-0.567,-4.099961183480138, **0**, **0**];

[t,q] = ode45(@f2,tspan,Y0);
```

Those two zeros encased in the asterisks should be able to be non-zero and I would like them to be for the model, but the solver fails when trying to change these to a non-zero value. MATLAB seems to be looping infinitely or at least doing something that causes the solver to freeze up. I may have not let it run long enough, but when I am able to just let it run I will and see if I get an error message. If these are zero, the output **q** is completely fine and I can plot those easily, but otherwise, I run into a problem. Is there a problem with my model described in `f2`? I have been getting pretty stuck. Thank you.

Comment: "the solver fails" you need to give more information. Matlab error messages are VERY USEFUL and they give helpful information. Read them, think about them, and include them in your question.

Comment: @David I would if I could, but it seems like MATLAB loops without being able to stop. I have potentially closed MATLAB too quickly, but as of right now, I have no idea why it fails to complete the solve,. I will make that more explicit in the problem. But even so, everything for the problem is there and I am sure that if someone with a more powerful computer could reach the error faster than mine can if I am unable to find anything.

Comment: Your code doesn't run, there are things undefined. Are the equations just stiff? In which case a stiff solver might help? Hard to say.